# Return the next value from an Excel table using INDEX, MATCH if first result is not an integer

Tags: excel, index-match

I am working on a Design Table to drive the creation of models.

If the user types values into the following columns the main table looks up some of the geometry based on size and then looks in a master lookup table to find the appropriate thread length based on Overall Length, Thread Pitch and Thread Type.

·         **Size** column (M10, M12, M16 etc.)

·         **Overall Length column (Overall length value)**

·         **Thread Pitch** column (Coarse, Fine, Extra Fine)

·         **Thread Type** column (Partial, Full)

I am using an Index / Match formula with multiple row criteria (Overall Length, Thread Pitch and Thread Type) and column criteria of the bolt size. With these criteria I expect to find a result somewhere in the master lookup table. However, since a standard Index / Match formula only returns the first result found I am often presented with non-integer results. I need the formula to check for the next result if the first is a non-integer value. In certain cases, this might not be enough and then I would reduce my row matching criteria to only look for Overall Length.

What is the best method to create a dynamic lookup formula to accomplish this?

Lookup Table

[image]

I have tried using the AGGREGATE(MIN function to try and find all integer values for a column trying to filter out non-integer values or errors but have had no luck.

I have tried multiple nested INDEX(MATCH( criteria to try and filter out results using IFNA or IFERROR but some data is always omitted.